# чтение pdf документа

Tags: javascript, python, php, pdf

Подскажите пожалуйста обработчики `pdf документов` для `python/php/js`.

**НО** для меня важно, чтобы данный обработчик не просто умел получить текст из документа, а еще видел: `полигоны`, `линии`, и другие элементы.

Comment: Для примера можно использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser). Я думаю она выполнит требуемые задачи.